# PHP update MySQL by id not name

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, wysiwyg

PHP uses the name from a form to update a record in a MySQL database, I want to update it using the `id` not the `name` like that:

```
<form action="myfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nametextbox" id="username"/>
    <input type="text" name="emailtextbox" id="email"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="update"/>
</form>
```

`myfile.php` >>(if I used the name)

```
if (isset($_POST['button'])){
    $title=$_POST['nametextbox'];
    $body=$_POST['emailtextbox'];
    mysql_connect("x", "y", "z")or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('c')or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET title='$title', body='$body' WHERE `id`='$_GET[update]'");
    mysql_close();
    header("location:mawdoo3.php");
}
```

How do I used the `id` and not the `name`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just set the `name` to the value you want it to be in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (at least not without JavaScript).  This has nothing to do with PHP, it's just HTML form standards .. the `name` attribute is the key of the value that gets sent to the server.  `id` never gets sent, and there is nothing you can do about it.